# How to send information from mysql database to ios app via python script

Tags: python, ios, mysql, swift, flask

I'd like to send information from a mysql database to an ios app using a python script and flask server. I currently am able to update the database from the app via the following script.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import make_response
from flask import request
import mysql.connector

#opens database connectionto "events" database
try:
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="Pass", database = "events")
    print("Connection OK")

except e:
    print("Connection failed: ", e)
#prepare a cursor object using cursor() method

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():

    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        event_id = request.form['a']
        poi = request.form['b']
        address = request.form['c']
        start_time = request.form['d']
        end_time = request.form['e']

        sql = "INSERT INTO events (event_id, poi, address, start_time, end_time) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
        val = (event_id, poi, address, start_time, end_time)


        try:
           # Execute the SQL command
           mycursor.execute(sql, val)
           # Commit your changes in the database
           mydb.commit()
           mydb.close()
        except e:
           # Rollback in case there is any error
           print("Error: ", e)
           mydb.rollback()

        return make_response("Success!", 200)

    elif flask.request.method == 'GET':


           return make_response("Success!", 200)

print("DB is closed")
```

I'm not sure how to implement the get method in my script and inside my app to get information form the database. The swift file I'd like to give information to looks like this

```
class AnnotationsVM: ObservableObject {
    @Published var annos = [MGLPointAnnotation]()
    @Published var annotationPlacementFailed: Bool
    @ObservedObject var VModel = ViewModel()
    @Published var visited: Bool


//Need to change this so the first annotation that is created is the user's annotation. Alternatively, we could just not have a user annotation and just use the standard blue circle as user location for now.

    init() {
        let annotation = MGLPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = "Shoe Store"
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.78, longitude: -73.98)
        annotation.subtitle = "Shoe Different"
        annotationPlacementFailed = false
        visited = true
        annos.append(annotation)


    }
}
```

I'd like to use the information from the database to create annotations inside the init function but don't know how to create the get function in swift.

In short, I need help writing database get methods in my flask python script and inside my ios app's swift file

Comment: You need to figure out what data format you want to use for your client-server communication. Commonly, JSON format is used. If you encoded your server data into JSON, you could send it in the response body. In Swift, it's then easy to decode JSON into an object

Comment: @New Dev say I choose JSON format, what would the code look like to send it to my app in the response body?

Comment: It depends on what you want to send. First, you need to query the database and get data and then convert that data into JSON format and send it to your ios app

Comment: @Kartikeya Sharma once the data is converted, I’m not sure how to send it via the python script and receive it with the swift code

Comment: sending data is very simple just return it like this ```jsonify({'data':sqldata})``` where sqldata is the data you converted to JSON. I think you don't even need jsonify anymore with new update in flask. I am not an expert in swift, this article can help ya https://medium.com/@calvinw/using-urlsession-to-retrieve-json-in-swift-1-getting-started-d929f3a49c67